# Should the distribution of my samples in my model be equal to to the original data set?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, model, train

In my original data set I see a distribution of 70% belongs to label A and 30% belongs to label B. For my train, validation and test set I maintained the same ratio. However, I wonder whether this is correct.

If 70% belongs to label A, is the probability that I classify my sample to label A then also higher than a classification to label B? Or should the model have a 50-50 (label A- label B) distribution so that model looks more at the selected features than at the distribution in the model? Or is that not relevant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After looking for some more info, I was helped with the following information: [link] (https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I was helped with the comments on the page [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)